# ¿Cómo subo imagen a jFrame con java?

Tags: java, netbeans

tengo una jframe como este
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el algún ladito quiero colocar un cuadro para poder subir una imagen que este en el pc, en si no necesito para que se guarde en la BD ya que solo es que quede la imagen para sacar todo el Jframe a pdf,
que utilizaría o que código, he buscado pero no encuentro, agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: ya tienes el sql para guardar en la base de datos? o como planeas hacerlo?

Comment: ya tengo un bd SQLite, hay ya guardo los datos ingresados de un formulario, lo que quiero es poder cargar la imagen al formulario, no es necesario guardarla en la bd poruqe rengo un boton de imprimir y pues lo que me imprime es el formulario que esta sobre un jPanel, y si la foto esta sobre el jpanel entonces me imprime eso..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya lo pude resolver
a un jlabel leinserto un icono que lo guarde en un packages,
el codigo a colocar es este

```
   private void btnSubirImagenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    JFileChooser jf = new JFileChooser();
    jf.setMultiSelectionEnabled(false);
    if (jf.showOpenDialog(this) == JFileChooser.OPEN_DIALOG) {
        rsdragdropfiles.RSDragDropFiles.setCopiar(jf.getSelectedFile().toString(), "src/img/usuario.png");
        lbImagen.setIcon(new ImageIcon(jf.getSelectedFile().toString()));
    }
}
```

el código va dentro del evento de un botón claramente

Comment: si te das cuenta que no la subes al jframe sino la guardas en el sistema de ficheros y luego simplemente la muestras?